# For which power do these series converge for odd and even termes

Tags: convergence-divergence

Hi I really don’t know how to solve this question:

For which a do these series converge ? 
$(\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!})^a $ only if i is odd 
$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(2^i)}{i!}$ only if i is even

I know the even serie converge to something smaller than e^2
But for the odd one I don’t know how to handle it.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I’m a little confused by the question. The first expression is not so much a series as it is a power of a series. Is it correct? Or should it perhaps be $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{(i!)^a}$? The second expression is a series, but there is a suspicious lack of an $a$. Was there supposed to be an $a$ somewhere?

Comment: The first series is bounded by $e^a$ , hence converges for every real $a$